# Rails 3 Pusher javascript not getting database updates

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, pusher

The following code nicely updates my page when a new event is pushed, however when the function 'current_msuser.countunread' is asked to get results from the database, in this case a record count, the count is not updated ...

The issue is the same in both development and production environments.

```
HTML CODE
<script>
    var pusher = new Pusher('xxx');
    var channel = pusher.subscribe('announcements');
    channel.bind('new-one', function(data) {
        xxx = "<%= current_msuser.countunread %>";
    document.getElementById("load-new-latest").innerHTML=xxx;
});
</script>

<a href="#" id="load-new-latest"><%= current_msuser.countunread %></a>

RUBY ACTIVERECORD CLASS

class Msuser < ActiveRecord::Base

    def countunread
        "#{Announcement.all.count.to_words remove_hyphen: true} new stories"
    end
end

THE PUSH NOTIFICATION IS SENT BY ...

class Announcement < ActiveRecord::Base 

    after_create :pusher_notify

    private

    def pusher_notify
        Pusher.app_id = 'xxx'
        Pusher.key = 'xxx'
        Pusher.secret = 'xxx'    

        Pusher['announcements'].trigger('new-one', {:message => self.message})
    end

 end
```

Any ideas why this is would be most appreciated.

Comment: Are you calling `Pusher['channel_name'].trigger( 'event_name', data )` / `Pusher.trigger('channel_name', 'event_name', data)` before calling `save` on your ActiveRecord object? I think we'll need to see more of the RoR code before being able to work our what may be going wrong.

Comment: I've added some code to the end, as you'll see the push is triggered by a record being added so it's definatly there.  Additionally I tested what happens when I replace the countunread() function return with a random number and in that case it works as expected.